# TypeError in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Here my problem:
I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined

```
export abstract class AbstractLogicExpression {
    protected _logicChildExpressions: AbstractLogicExpression[] = Array();
    protected _precedence = 0;
    protected _parsed = false;
    protected _expressionType = "";

    protected rightAssociative = false;

    public toDNF() {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.logicChildExpressions.length; i++) {
            let actualLogicExpression: AbstractLogicExpression = this.logicChildExpressions[i];

            if (actualLogicExpression._expressionType == "~") {

                let logicConjunction = actualLogicExpression.logicChildExpressions[0];

                let var1 = logicConjunction.logicChildExpressions[0];
                let var2 = logicConjunction.logicChildExpressions[1];

                if (logicConjunction._expressionType == "*") {
                    actualLogicExpression.logicChildExpressions[0] = new LogicOr();
                    //actualLogicExpression.logicChildExpressions[0].add(new LogicNeg(var1));
                    //actualLogicExpression.logicChildExpressions[0].add(new LogicNeg(var2));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get this error because of the line before the two commented lines:

```
actualLogicExpression.logicChildExpressions[0] = new LogicOr();
```

I tested it by comment and uncomment the lines, because I get no line number in the error message.

Does someone know what I can do?
If you need a little more code. I can post something...

Here the code of LogicOr:
https://pastebin.com/T28Zjbtb

Comment: I guess something is wrong with LogicOr. Can you post the definition of that class? Also maybe this is relevant? https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14734

Comment: Your right if I replace LogiOr with null the error disappears. But why?

Comment: Are you importing it properly and sure that it's getting bundled properly? It seems to me like the class doesn't exist anymore at runtime?

Comment: Well its a anuglar app. And I import LogicOr correctly: https://pastebin.com/CyuxVCQR

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You get an error on this line:

> actualLogicExpression.logicChildExpressions[0] = new LogicOr();

The error message is

> Uncaught TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined

It is very easy to understand once you are familiar with Classes and how they work (https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/classes.html).

The error means that `new LogicOr` is failing because `LogicOr` is extending something that is `undefined`. Simple example:

```
let Bar; 
class Foo extends Bar { } // Uncaught TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined
```

## More

Fix the bug in `LogicOr` and its inheritance chain.

Comment: But LogicOr extends correctly from AbstractLogicExpression. Is Typescript unable to handle circular dependencies?

Comment: `Is Typescript unable to handle circular dependencies?` This is a limitation of commonjs. Recommend removing them. For analysis I use https://alm-tools.gitbooks.io/alm/content/features/dependency.html

Comment: I solves the problem with the circular dependency and now it works

Answer (score 21):

To add to this, the actual problem here with the circular dependency is because one of resources that have not loaded before they are used. You will also get this error if your resources are loading out of order.

Consider this example that uses gulp to compile:

```
// File Parent.ts
export class Parent {
    public prop: string = "prop";
}
//File Child.ts
export class Child extends Parent {
    public prop2: string = "prop2";
}
```

and the gulp to compile

```
gulp.task('compile-js', function () {
return gulp.src(['code/Child.js', 'code/Parent.js'])
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(concat('app.bundle.js'))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/build'));
});
```

The output file app.bundle.js will error with "Uncaught TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined" because the resulting code will first execute the creation of the Child class (which has the dependency on the Parent class) before the parent class has been loaded.

If you look at the resulting javascript you will get:

```
var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || (function () {
    var extendStatics = Object.setPrototypeOf ||
        ({ __proto__: [] } instanceof Array && function (d, b) { d.__proto__ = b; }) ||
        function (d, b) { for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p]; };
    return function (d, b) {
        extendStatics(d, b);
        function __() { this.constructor = d; }
        d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());
    };
})();
var Child = /** @class */ (function (_super) {
    __extends(Child, _super);
    function Child() {
        var _this = _super !== null && _super.apply(this, arguments) || this;
        _this.prop2 = "prop2";
        return _this;
    }
    return Child;
}(Parent));
var Parent = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Parent() {
        this.prop = "prop";
    }
    return Parent;
}());
```

And when you run this you will get:

Uncaught TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined
    at setPrototypeOf ()

To fix this, simply change the order of the resources in your gulp file or whatever method you are using to prepare or load the javascript for the page.

```
return gulp.src(['code/Parent.js', 'code/Child.js'])
```

There are many ways that this can be dealt with, this is just an example to help you understand the problem and how you might fix it. Whichever way you find to fix the problem, in the end, the error is asking the javascript engine to do something you haven't yet given instructions for at the time of execution.

Hope this helps, 
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

For the desperate souls out there unfortunate enough to have to work with Javascript, this might help you: what fixed it for me is to create an `index.ts` class that exported the classes in the right order, and then make all my imports from the index file instead of from a relative path. Here's what the file looks like:

```js
export { default as BasePage } from './BasePage' // abstract class
export { default as ProtectedAppPage } from './ProtectedAppPage' // abstract extending BasePage class
export { default as RegistrationForm } from './registration/forms/RegistrationForm' // abstract class extending ProtectedAppPage

export { default as ForgotPasswordPage } from './authentication/ForgotPasswordPage' // concrete class extending BasePage
export { default as HomeAddressForm } from './registration/forms/HomeAddressForm' // concrete class extending RegistrationForm
export { default as MfaPage } from './authentication/MfaPage' // concrete class extending ProtectedAppPage
```

Now let's take a look at imports.

```js
// before
import HomeAddressForm from './registration/forms/HomeAddressForm'
// after
import HomeAddressForm from './index'
```

Making these changes was enough to resolve it for me.