# Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined

Tags: typescript, vue.js

While trying to create a codesandbox to reproduce a bug, I faced another problem.

Here is my codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-typescript-example-o7xsv

The error is:

> Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined

Is seems to be related to class extension. `HelloWorld` class is extending `Vue`, and Vue is imported:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from "vue";
import Component from "vue-class-component";

@Component
export default class HelloWorld extends Vue {
  msg = "HelloWorld";
}
</script>
```

Console error :

[image: Console error]

Compiled version:

[image: Console error - Compiled]
I already saw this thread, but didn't help:
[TypeError in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44421810/typeerror-in-typescript)

Comment: The question should contain all relevant code, not just a link to it. Please, post it.

Comment: Added HelloWorld code

Comment: I posted an answer. I have no recommendations how Codesandbox can be fixed because the template you based it on is broken. If you're after practical solution, try something like https://stackblitz.com/edit/vuejs-starter-typescript

Comment: Thanks for this link, I will use it. You say the codesandbox template is broken... but it can't be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is specific to currently used [Vue+TypeScript template](https://codesandbox.io/s/0p1n3j0orw). The template doesn't make use of [synthetic default exports](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) and requires to import Vue as

```
import * as Vue from "vue";
```

instead of

```
import Vue from "vue";
```

The setup seems to be using Babel for transpilation and TypeScript for type checking.

Regular modules are broken as well, they are exported as default exports:

```
export default Vue.component({
...
```

But in order to work, they should be imported as `*`:

```
import * as HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld";
```

Another problem is how `vue-class-component` and `@Component` decorator are used. As a rule of thumb, TypeScript/ES.Next decorators are expected to be [factories](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#decorator-factories). This makes the use of decorators consistent because they may or may not accept arguments. This also mitigates a problem when a decorator is accidentally not called when it should. It should be used as:

```
@Component()
export default class HelloWorld extends Vue {...}
```

Comment: Is used Vue+TypeScript template, that's right. But I then edited tsconfig.json and added : "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true and "esModuleInterop": true.

Comment: See the explanation. TS config doesn't affect how modules are transpiled here, that's the problem. I have no ideas how it can be fixed. That original unforked template requires to import default export as `import * as HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld"` suggests that it's faulty.